# Understanding the notation $P(\{X<2\}\cup\{Y<2\})$.

Tags: probability

I'm studying for an exam, and I am looking at old exam papers. I stumbled upon a notation I did not quite understand. First of all I have the PMF for the independent discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

$$
P_X(x)=\begin{cases}
0.2\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{ if $x=0$}\\
0.3\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{ if $x=1$}\\
0.5\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{ if $x=2$}\\
0\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{ otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$
P_Y(y)=\begin{cases}
0.3\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{ if $y=0$}\\
0.4\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{ if $y=1$}\\
0.3\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{ if $y=2$}\\
0\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{ otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}
$$

I need to calculate the probability $P(\{X<2\}\cup\{Y<2\})$. I've already been given the result which is $0.85$, but I can't quite figure out how to get there.

Comment: The prob that $X < 2$ it seems to be 0,5 and that of $Y < 2$ 0.7

Comment: $\cup$ is set union: it represents the "sum" of the two events.

Comment: You can't solve the problem without knowing something about the relation between $X$ and $Y$.  Are they independent?  If not, what is their joint distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ P(X<2) = P(X=0)+P(X=1)=0.5$$ and $$P(Y<2) = P(Y=0)+P(Y=1)=0.7$$

Since there is no joint distribution I assume $X,Y$ are independent, so if we use inclusion exclusion principle we get:

$$P(\{X<2\}\cup\{Y<2\}) = P(X<2) -P(Y<2)+P(\{X<2\}\cap\{Y<2\}) $$ 
 $$= P(X<2) +P(Y<2)-P(\{X<2\})\cdot P(\{Y<2\}) $$
 $$= 0.5 +0.7-0.5\cdot 0.7 = 0.85 $$
which matches with your result.

Comment: Thanks, I was working under the assumption, that since the variables are independent, that I would just have to add their probabilities because of the union. This clears things up though!